# ¿Cómo solucionó el error unlink(): Resource temporarily unavailable in, en php?

Tags: php

Tengo un error y es que, tengo una carpeta en la cual subo unos documentos, y cuando se suben unos nuevos debe eliminar los que ya estaban en la carpeta, la cuestión es que no me deja, me aparece el siguiente error:

> **Warning**:  unlink(C:/xampp/htdocs/Jomar/induccion/documents/politicas/POLITICA JOMAR INVERSIONES SAS 2019.pdf): Resource temporarily unavailable in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Jomar\induccion\controllers\FilesController.php** on line **21**

El código en el que ocurre el error es el siguiente:

```
public static function deleteFiles($ruta){
            $files = glob("$ruta*.pdf"); //obtenemos todos los nombres de los ficheros
            if($files != null){
                foreach($files as $file){
                    if(is_file($file))
                    $res = unlink($file); //elimino el fichero
                }
            }else{
                $res = true;
            }
            return $res;
        }
```

Y en este es dónde llamo a dicha función:

```
$dir = "/Jomar/induccion/documents/";

if(isset($_FILES["politicas"]) && $_FILES["politicas"] != null){
        $fichero = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."{$dir}politicas/";
        if(FilesController::deleteFiles($fichero)){
            for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES["politicas"]["tmp_name"]); $i++){
                if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["politicas"]["tmp_name"][$i], $fichero.basename($_FILES["politicas"]["name"][$i]))){
                    $cont++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Sí alguien puede ayudarme, se lo agradezco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que el archivo esta siendo usado por otro proceso, o quizá él mismo.

Intenta cambiando el `if(is_file($file))` por `if(is_writable($file))`

Con eso revisas si puedes escribir ese archivo, ya que si puedes escribirlo puedes eliminarlo.